# Convert square matrix to binary array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have square matrix like this. (used pearson correlation)

```html
            ACSM3     ACSX12    ADXM28  ...   UGT2B15      VCAN        XK
ACSM3    1.000000  0.929347  0.999914  ...  0.986433  0.999947 -0.999680
ACSX12    0.929347  1.000000  0.924428  ...  0.977350  0.925496 -0.919704
ADXM28   0.999914  0.924428  1.000000  ...  0.984196  0.999996 -0.999925
ADAM28   0.999976  0.926774  0.999981  ...  0.985275  0.999994 -0.999831
ADH1B   -0.999509 -0.917317 -0.999834  ... -0.980802 -0.999778  0.999982
ADTRP   -0.999039 -0.912273 -0.999528  ... -0.978290 -0.999438  0.999828
AEBP1    0.983312  0.846668  0.985611  ...  0.940104  0.985133 -0.987601
AKR1B10 -0.999658 -0.919371 -0.999915  ... -0.981800 -0.999874  1.000000
UBL3     0.997347  0.900002  0.998215  ...  0.971864  0.998043 -0.998870
UGT2B15  0.986433  0.977350  0.984196  ...  1.000000  0.984690 -0.981961
VCAN     0.999947  0.925496  0.999996  ...  0.984690  1.000000 -0.999887
XK      -0.999680 -0.919704 -0.999925  ... -0.981961 -0.999887  1.000000
```

I need to pairing all column with rows like this ;

```html
ACSM3 ACSM3 1.00000000
ACSM3 ACSX12 0.92934700
ACSM3 ADXM28 0.99991400
ACSM3 ADAM28 0.99997600
ACSM3 ADH1B -0.99950900
ACSM3 ADTRP -0.99903900
ACSM3 AEBP1 0.98331200
ACSM3 AKR1B10 -0.99965800
ACSM3 UBL3 0.99734700
ACSM3 UGT2B15 0.98643300
ACSM3 VCAN 0.99994700
ACSM3 XK -0.99968000
ACSX12 ACSM3 ….
ACSX12 ADXM28 ….
ACSX12 ADAM28 ….
ACSX12 ADH1B ….
ACSX12 ADTRP ….
ACSX12 AEBP1 ….
ACSX12 AKR1B10 ….
ACSX12 UBL3 ….
ACSX12 UGT2B15 ….
ACSX12 VCAN ….
ACSX12 XK ….
```

Is there any fast solution?
Or I will do this with For loop.
Thank you.

Comment: Look at `stack()` or `melt()`.

Comment: maybe `flatten`?

Comment: @ScottBoston stack is right answer, thank you sir. df2 = df.stack().reset_index()
df2.columns = list('abc') works for me.